# is there any limit for using window.open() in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any limit of using `window.open("URL");` in JavaScript? 
 when I tried to open three windows using `window.open("URL")` after opening the second window the third window didn't open separately but it just refreshed the contents of first window and showed the contents of the third window in there.

Comment: Usually you will supply the `window.open()` call with a target window:  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.open

Comment: Could we have some code please(what urls are you opening?)

Comment: I don't think that the HTML/Javascript standard has any limit here, but I think the popup blocker of your web browser is setting a limit to prevent websites from "spamming" too many popups. I still remember those prank websites from the 90s which created literally hundreds of popups when you visited them so you had to kill the browser process to be able to continue working. You don't see these anymore, because web browser now prevent this from happening.

Comment: ok but if the browser is limiting then it should just stop the new windows to open why show the contents in a already opened window ?

Comment: May be it is browser specific. What browser and which version you are using?

Comment: No its not Browser specific it is same in Firefox, chrome and chromium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
window.open(url, targetName);
```

If the targetName is different,the windows will open  separately.You can set the targetName randomly to open windows separately.
For Example,

```
window.open(url,Math.floor(Math.random() * 80000));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using "_blank" as the target window should open a new window every time (just like with `<a href="url" target="_blank">link</a>`). For example:

```
window.open("URL", "_blank");
```

But opening multiple windows can be subject to various pop-up blocking features and plugins.