# Looping through array of file urls opens only first URL Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I've this short script to open URL's:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("a.Mylinks");
var myarray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var link = x[i].href;
  myarray.push(link);
}
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
  window.open(myarray[i], "_blank");
}
```

Array responds back with correct URLs, first URL opens and that is it, loop stops.
Any ideas why this is happening and how this can be fixed? Any additional links or information would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there any limit for using window.open() in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778726/is-there-any-limit-for-using-window-open-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that browser you're using blocks an opening of too much tabs at the same time. Try disabling that blocking, usually you can find the needed button for that in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Note Browser can block as opening of too much tabs at the same time.**
```

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("a.Mylinks");
var myarray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var link = x[i].href;
  window.open(x[i].href,Math.floor(Math.random() * 80000));
}
```

```html
<a class='Mylinks' href='https://google.com'></a>
<a class='Mylinks' href='https://stackoverflow.com'></a>
<a class='Mylinks' href='https://nodejs.org'></a>
```

Comment: It did block on one website. The script I provided was opening multiple tabs, but still opened the same link. Your provided script worked without random function as well. Thank you

Comment: @c0zero oh great. please upvote my answer and accept my answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just change the target name from _blank to random series like `"_blank" + i`, then check it.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
       window.open(link, '_blank' + i); 
 }
```